# How to solve the problem that the global variable is not defined in python?

Tags: python, global-variables

I'm writing a script for stock / crpyto trading. A very crude strategy is to buy when the RSI (a technical indicator in stock) reaches 50 and sell when the RSI falls below 50 for 3 consecutive days or below 40 in a single day. My origin script is like this:

```
def simpleRSIstrategy(indicator, threshold1 = 50, threshold2 = 40, days = 3):
    
    buySellTable = dict()
    
    # simple RSI strategy
      
    hold = False
    count = 0  
    
    for i in range(len(indicator)):
        # buying strategy
        if indicator['RSI7'][i] > threshold1 and not hold:
            date = indicator.index[i]
            buySellTable[date] = 'Buy'
            hold = True  
            
        # selling strategy    
        if indicator['RSI7'][i] < threshold1 and hold:
            count += 1
            if count == days or indicator['RSI7'][i] < threshold2:
                date = indicator.index[i]
                buySellTable[date] = 'Sell'
                hold = False
                count = 0       
        if indicator['RSI7'][i] > threshold1 and hold:
            count = 0
    return buySellTable
```

What this script is supposed to do is applying the aforementioned simple RSI strategy and return the 'buySellTable', which is a dictionary with the dates as keys and 'Buy' and 'Sell' as items. There is nothing wrong with this script. Since it's a crude strategy, it's necessary to get optimized. I want to split it into two parts - buying strategy and selling strategy so that I can do the optimization respectively. Then I rewrote it into the following scripts:

```
def simpleRSIstrategy_split(indicator, threshold1 = 50, threshold2 = 40, days = 3):
    
    
    buySellTable = dict()
    hold = False
    count = 0 
    startIdx = 0
   
    while True:
       
        simpleBuyStrategy_split(indicator, threshold1)
     
        simpleSellStrategy_split(indicator, threshold1, threshold2, days)
        
        if startIdx == len(indicator)-1:
            break
        
    return buySellTable
```

```
def simpleBuyStrategy_split(indicator, threshold1):
    global startIdx, hold, buySellTable
    
    for i in range(startIdx, len(indicator)):
            if indicator['RSI7'][i] > threshold1 and not hold:
                date = indicator.index[i]
                buySellTable[date] = 'Buy'
                hold = True  
                startIdx = i+1
                break

def simpleSellStrategy_split(indicator, threshold1, threshold2,  days):
    global startIdx, count, hold, buySellTable
    
    for i in range(startIdx, len(indicator)):
        if indicator['RSI7'][i] < threshold1 and hold:
            count += 1
            if count == days or indicator['RSI7'][i] < threshold2:
                date = indicator.index[i]
                buySellTable[date] = 'Sell'
                hold = False
                count = 0  
                startIdx = i+1
                break
        if indicator['RSI7'][i] > threshold1 and hold:
            count = 0
```

In the 'simpleRSIstrategy_split' script, I want to treat buySellTable, hold, count and startIdx as global variables that can be used and edited by the scripts 'simpleBuyStrategy_split' and 'simpleSellStrategy_split'. But I got the error message when I run the script: name 'startIdx' is not defined. I check the output from the console and found that when it's excuting the line

```
for i in range(startIdx, len(indicator)):
```

in the script 'simpleBuyStrategy_split', it complains that startIdx is not defined. But I already defined it as a global variable. I don't know why this happens and how can I solve it?

Comment: You defined the value for `startIdx` locally inside `simpleRSIstrategy_split`.

Comment: Yeah. I removed it from 'simpleRSIstrategy_split' and added it in the main script but I still got the same error message...

Comment: In python indentation is part of the syntax. Don't just indent the first line but the rest not. This results in wrong code! use triple back quotes for code blocks, not indentation by 4 spaces!

Comment: The `global` statement does not create a new global variable, as you seem to think. All it does is to determine how references to that name are to be interpreted in the local scope. Initialize the variable at module level (outside your function). That way it will already exist when your `range()` call tries to get its value. As your code stands,the interpreter goes looking in the global scope for that variable and does not find it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got the scoping wrong. Python is a lexically scoped language.

Without knowing, you are writing closures. Meaning you use variables in `simpleBuyStrategy_split` and `simpleSellStrategy_split` which are not in the function argument list - but outside the function definition.

Basically

```
    buySellTable = dict()
    hold = False
    count = 0 
    startIdx = 0
```

You treat them as if they would have dynamic scoping.
(that they would change dependent where these two functions are called).

Since python arguments are mostly call-by-reference (due to performance reasons) - so they work like C pointers, the arguments themselves are changed if they are changed in the function body - except when they are deep-copied explicitely in the function body.

Therefore you could use them as if they are dynamically scoped, if you just pass them as function arguments.

Like this:

```
# first define them globally

buySellTable = dict()
hold = False
count = 0 
startIdx = 0

# then in each function definition, pass them as function arguments

def simpleRSIstrategy_split(indicator, threshold1 = 50, threshold2 = 40, days = 3, buySellTable=buySellTable, hold=hold, count=count, startIdx=startIdx):

    while True:
       
        simpleBuyStrategy_split(indicator, threshold1, buySellTable=buySellTable, hold=hold, count=count, startIdx=startIdx)
     
        simpleSellStrategy_split(indicator, threshold1, threshold2, days, buySellTable=buySellTable, hold=hold, count=count, startIdx=startIdx)
        
        if startIdx == len(indicator)-1:
            break
        
    return buySellTable

def simpleBuyStrategy_split(indicator, threshold1, buySellTable=buySellTable, hold=hold, count=count, startIdx=startIdx):
    
    for i in range(startIdx, len(indicator)):
            if indicator['RSI7'][i] > threshold1 and not hold:
                date = indicator.index[i]
                buySellTable[date] = 'Buy'
                hold = True  
                startIdx = i+1
                break

def simpleSellStrategy_split(indicator, threshold1, threshold2,  days, buySellTable=buySellTable, hold=hold, count=count, startIdx=startIdx):

    for i in range(startIdx, len(indicator)):
        if indicator['RSI7'][i] < threshold1 and hold:
            count += 1
            if count == days or indicator['RSI7'][i] < threshold2:
                date = indicator.index[i]
                buySellTable[date] = 'Sell'
                hold = False
                count = 0  
                startIdx = i+1
                break
        if indicator['RSI7'][i] > threshold1 and hold:
            count = 0
```

I see, somehow you realized that they have globally to refer,
but then, the simpleRSI function split must also do it:

```
buySellTable = dict()
hold = False
count = 0 
startIdx = 0
   
def simpleRSIstrategy_split(indicator, threshold1 = 50, threshold2 = 40, days = 3):
    global buySellTable, hold, count, startIdx
    
    while True:
       
        simpleBuyStrategy_split(indicator, threshold1)
     
        simpleSellStrategy_split(indicator, threshold1, threshold2, days)
        
        if startIdx == len(indicator)-1:
            break
        
    return buySellTable
```

And the other two functions then as you had them. This might also work.

But this is not so nice. Because one should avoid global variables.

#### Solution: Encapsulate Using Classes

In Python, you would avoid global variables by using classes.
You could create a class where the global variables are class Attributes. (prepended by: `self.`
And these three functions are methods of the class.
Since they have then to refer to these four variables using `self.`
you don't need the 'global' delcarations in them.
And the class itself is encapsulated.

Like this:

```
class SimpleRSITrader:
    def __init__(self, indicator, threshold1 = 50, threshold2 = 40, days = 3, rsi='RSI7'):
        self.buy_sell_table = {}
        self.hold = False
        self.count = 0
        self.start_idx = 0
        self.indicator = indicator
        self.thresh1 = threshold1
        self.thrseh2 = threshold2
        self.days = days
        self.rsi = rsi
    
    def run(self):
        while True:
            self.buy()
            self.sell()     
            if self.startIdx == len(self.indicator)-1:
                break
        return self.buy_sell_table
    
    def buy(self):
        for i in range(self.start_idx, len(self.indicator)):
            if self.indicator[self.rsi][i] > self.thresh1 and not self.hold:
                date = self.indicator.index[i]
                self.buy_sell_table[date] = 'Buy'
                self.hold = True
                self.start_idx = i + 1
                break
                
    def sell(self):
        for i in range(self.start_idx, len(self.indicator)):
            if self.hold:
                if self.indictaor[self.rsi] < self.thresh1:
                    self.count += 1
                    if count == self.days or self.indictoar[self.rsi][i] < self.thresh2:
                        date = self.indicator.index[i]    
                        self.buy_sell_table[date] = 'Sell'
                        self.hold = False
                        self.count = 0
                        self.start_idx = i + 1
                        break
                if self.indicator[self.rsi][i] > self.thresh1:
                    self.count = 0
```

The good thing of this is, you can anytime from outside check the status of the attributes. And thus also communicate with other parts of the program - while you don't have global variables - because the previously global variables are now encapsulated in the class - therefore packed into objects.

So the idea is that for each indicator with new threshold settings and day settings you create a new instance for the simple RSI strategy.

This class, you can reuse even for different RSI's (other than 'RSI7').

Through encapsulation, the context for your buy and sell becomes clear - thus the method names or attribute names become simpler too - therefore everything more easily readable and your code is structured - every former global variables and functions are now encapsulated into the class - thus the code is clearly structured and the context of each of them clear - therefore you can be shorter with your names.

Comment: Thank you soooo much for your answer with so many details. I finally fixed the problem using an OOP appraoch as you mentioned. It's quite convient and clear without using the global variables.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you are unclear about the usage of the keyword `global`. The `global` keyword is used to access variables defined in a global scope inside a function. Consider this example,

```
var = 0
def func():
    var = 2
func()
print (var)
```

Here you get the output:

```
0
>>>
```

because a local copy of the variable `var` is created when we call `func()`. This copy of `var`, if modified, will not affect the global copy (i.e. the `var = 0` defined outside `func()` in the global scope). Hence we get `0` as the output, since `print (var)` is in the global scope.
Now consider this:

```
var = 0
def func():
    global var
    var = 2
func()
print (var)
```

Here you get the output:

```
2
>>>
```

because when `func()` is called Python searches for `var` in the global scope, finds it, and changes its value to `2`. Hence `print (var)` will show `2` because the global variable `var` was changed inside the function when we wrote `var = 2` after `global var`.

But if you do something like this:

```
def func():
    global var
    var = 2
func()
print (var)
```

Here you get `NameError` while executing `print (var)` because `var` was never defiend in the global scope. When `func()` is called, Python searches for `var` in the global scope but doesn't find it and so just a local copy of the variable `var` is created. So `global var` in this case is pretty much redundant because `var` was never defined in the global scope.

Simply put, the solution to your problem would be to put

```
buySellTable = dict()
hold = False
count = 0 
startIdx = 0
```

outside the function `simpleRSIstrategy_split()`. Your code should then work as expected.